# Return Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm executing below query in, but return duplicate rows when we do not have any records for "LastMonth" and "CurrentMonth". Please let me know where is the issue?

```
**Output:**
Project ProCount CurrentDateAvg thisWeekAvg thisMonthAvg lastMonthAvg           
xyz         0            0          0.19       0.09       0
xyz         5            0          0.0         0.0       0


WITH 
ThisWeek AS (SELECT  'xyz' as 'Project_Name', 0.19 as 'thisWeekAvg' ), 
ThisMonth AS ( SELECT  'xyz' as 'Project_Name', 0.09 as 'thisMonthAvg'), 
LastMonth AS( SELECT  'xyz' as 'Project_Name', 0 as 'lastMonthAvg'  where 1=2), 
CurrentDate AS( SELECT  'xyz' as 'Project_Name', 0 as 'CurrentDateAvg'  where 1=2), 
ProjectCount AS( SELECT  'xyz' as 'Project_Name', 5 AS 'ProCount' ) 
              SELECT 
                             COALESCE(w.Project_Name, m.Project_Name, l.Project_Name,c.Project_Name,pc.Project_Name) AS 'Project',
                             COALESCE(pc.ProCount,0) 'ProCount', 
                             COALESCE(c.CurrentDateAvg,0) 'CurrentDateAvg', 
                             COALESCE(w.thisWeekAvg,0) 'thisWeekAvg', 
                             COALESCE(m.thisMonthAvg,0) 'thisMonthAvg', 
                             COALESCE(l.lastMonthAvg,0) 'lastMonthAvg' 
                             FROM 
                             ThisWeek w 
                             FULL OUTER JOIN ThisMonth m ON         w.Project_Name = m.Project_Name
                             FULL OUTER JOIN LastMonth l    ON         m.Project_Name = l.Project_Name
                             FULL OUTER JOIN ProjectCount pc ON    l.Project_Name = pc.Project_Name 
                             FULL OUTER JOIN CurrentDate c ON         pc.Project_Name = c.Project_Name
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including enough information that we could run everything ourselves (such as on dbfiddle.uk) and see the behaviour you're seeing. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: You are a seasoned SO user, no? Where is the sample data? Minimal reproducible sample? You have many full joins that might explain duplications but we don't have information.

Comment: Actually it is quite obvious why you have duplications. In one of those w, m, l, pc, c there is more than one match for the same Project_Name.

Comment: Your query fails for me. You request data in all your CTEs from the column `xyz`, but you have no `FROM` in any of the CTEs so there *is* no column `xyz`.

Comment: @ThomA, I believe it was a typo he used double quotes instead of single.

Comment: It is because some of your later joins use these CTEs to join to, so when there are no records for these, you get no match in the full join (since `NULL <> xyz) so you return this as a new row. If you change all joins to a CTE that has rows then [duplicates are removed](https://dbfiddle.uk/sKS1m9WZ), but knowing which one has rows is probably not known till run-time. You may want to [select from a project table and left join to all your CTEs](https://dbfiddle.uk/XYMZ7cEm), although this feels like something that would be much more efficiently handled using conditional aggregation

Comment: This should help you see what is happening... https://dbfiddle.uk/SYh0PDRM Or you could have built up the query one join at a time and seen for yourself when the behaviour arose (basic debugging)

Comment: If a project has data in at least One table, will ProjectCount be guarantees to also have data for that project?

Comment: Why do so few of your questions have accepted answers???

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behavior because you aren't handling your `NULL` values in your `JOIN`s.

Let's number them for ease:

```
ThisWeek w --1
FULL OUTER JOIN ThisMonth m ON w.Project_Name = m.Project_Name --2
FULL OUTER JOIN LastMonth l ON m.Project_Name = l.Project_Name --3
FULL OUTER JOIN ProjectCount pc ON l.Project_Name = pc.Project_Name --4
FULL OUTER JOIN CurrentDate c ON pc.Project_Name = c.Project_Name --5
```

So we have:

1. This Week with a project called "xyz".
2. This Month, with a project of "xyz" to JOIN to This Week (which also has "xyz")
3. Last Month, with no projects, to `JOIN` to This Month (no rows `JOIN`ed)
4. Current Data, with no projects, to J`OIN` to Last Month (no rows `JOIN`ed)
5. Project Count, with a project of "xyz", to `JOIN` to no rows; creates a new row due to `FULL OUTER JOIN`. `NULL <> 'xyz'`

For stuff like this you likely want an `IN`:

```sql
WITH
    ThisWeek AS (
        SELECT
            'xyz' AS Project_Name,
            0.19 AS thisWeekAvg
    ),
    ThisMonth AS (
        SELECT
            'xyz' AS Project_Name,
            0.09 AS thisMonthAvg
    ),
    LastMonth AS (
        SELECT
            'xyz' AS Project_Name,
            0 AS lastMonthAvg
        WHERE
            1 = 2
    ),
    CurrentDate AS (
        SELECT
            'xyz' AS Project_Name,
            0 AS CurrentDateAvg
        WHERE
            1 = 2
    ),
    ProjectCount AS (
        SELECT
            'xyz' AS Project_Name,
            5 AS ProCount
    )
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        w.Project_Name,
        m.Project_Name,
        l.Project_Name,
        c.Project_Name,
        pc.Project_Name
    ) AS Project,
    COALESCE(pc.ProCount, 0) ProCount,
    COALESCE(c.CurrentDateAvg, 0) CurrentDateAvg,
    COALESCE(w.thisWeekAvg, 0) thisWeekAvg,
    COALESCE(m.thisMonthAvg, 0) thisMonthAvg,
    COALESCE(l.lastMonthAvg, 0) lastMonthAvg
FROM
    ThisWeek w
    FULL OUTER JOIN ThisMonth m ON w.Project_Name = m.Project_Name --WE don't need an IN here
    FULL OUTER JOIN LastMonth l ON l.Project_Name IN (w.Project_Name,m.Project_Name)
    FULL OUTER JOIN ProjectCount pc ON pc.Project_Name IN (w.Project_Name,m.Project_Name,l.Project_Name)
    FULL OUTER JOIN CurrentDate c ON c.Project_Name IN (w.Project_Name,m.Project_Name,l.Project_Name,pc.Project_Name);
```

Comment: I often find that UNION ALL and PIVOT performs better than IN/OR based joins.

Comment: I thought about that, but my concern was the differing data types, @MatBailie . Feel free to provide that as an alternative solution though; the OP would then be able to race their horses.

Comment: I'm on a phone and don't have the patience :)

Comment: Or, looking at the data, LEFT JOIN everything on to ProjectCount, IFF the op confirms it always has data.

Comment: That wuold make more sense, @MatBailie . I add, I *assumed* that they knew what they were doing with the `FULL OUTER JOIN`. ;)

Comment: Dangerous assumption ;)

Comment: Indeed, @MatBailie .

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is not match to pc.Project_Name = l.Project_Name.

```
WITH ThisWeek
AS (SELECT 'xyz' AS Project_Name,
           0.19 AS thisWeekAvg),
     ThisMonth
AS (SELECT 'xyz' AS Project_Name,
           0.09 AS thisMonthAvg),
     LastMonth
AS (SELECT 'xyz' AS Project_Name,
           0 AS lastMonthAvg
    WHERE 1 = 2),
     CurrentDate
AS (SELECT 'xyz' AS Project_Name,
           0 AS CurrentDateAvg
    WHERE 1 = 2),
     ProjectCount
AS (SELECT 'xyz' AS Project_Name,
           5 AS ProCount)
SELECT COALESCE(w.Project_Name, m.Project_Name, l.Project_Name, c.Project_Name, pc.Project_Name) AS Project,
       COALESCE(pc.ProCount, 0) ProCount,
       COALESCE(c.CurrentDateAvg, 0) CurrentDateAvg,
       COALESCE(w.thisWeekAvg, 0) thisWeekAvg,
       COALESCE(m.thisMonthAvg, 0) thisMonthAvg,
       COALESCE(l.lastMonthAvg, 0) lastMonthAvg
FROM ThisWeek w
    FULL OUTER JOIN ThisMonth m
        ON w.Project_Name = m.Project_Name
    FULL OUTER JOIN LastMonth l
        ON m.Project_Name = l.Project_Name
           OR l.Project_Name = w.Project_Name
    FULL OUTER JOIN ProjectCount pc
        ON l.Project_Name = pc.Project_Name
           OR pc.Project_Name = w.Project_Name
           OR pc.Project_Name = m.Project_Name
    FULL OUTER JOIN CurrentDate c
        ON pc.Project_Name = c.Project_Name
           OR c.Project_Name = w.Project_Name
           OR c.Project_Name = m.Project_Name
           OR c.Project_Name = l.Project_Name;
```

Comment: How does this materially differ from the IN based answer preceding yours?

Comment: @MatBailie\ what do you mean_ Who said it materially differs from IN based answer preceding? Have you ever thought I posted it before seeing it?